# solr - complex data structure

Tags: solr

I have the following data structure for creating index.
user
  userid
  username
  userstatus
  friends
    friendid
    friendstatus
    friendcreateddate

I think dynamic field wont work for me since I need to query based on specific field names.

I have search based on friendstatus and friendcreateddate. Can someone advise me on best possible document structure?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very simple data structure. You just need to look at an example schema.xml and put your own field definitions in there. A field like "friends" would be declared as multiValued="true" and the userid would be tagged `<uniqueKey>`

Follow this guide http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml
and ignore complicated stuff like dynamic fields which you probably don't need.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the help. I am doing the same now. I have created a multivalued field for friends. The friends info is created as a string by concatinating with :: . eg. id::status::createddate::updateddate. Here my friends's search based on status works fine. But I need to develop query for retrieving records based on updated date in descending order. Any suggestion on this?